# Reversing a Referenced Range Order in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to transfer data from workbook x into workbook y. I want to copy a horizontal range from workbook x, transpose and reverse the range and then paste the values in workbook y. I would it to look like this:

Workbook x

| ColumnX | ColumnXx | ColumnXy | ColumnXz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 8 | 10 | 7 |

Workbook y

| Column |
| --- |
| 7 |
| 10 |
| 8 |
| 9 |

So far, I can transpose the values but I've been searching how to reverse the range and haven't found any solutions using VBA. My current code:

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant


Set y= ThisWorkbook
Set x= Workbooks.Open("FileName.xls", CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)

vals = x.Sheets("SheetSource").Range("G10:C10").Value

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G8:G12").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vals)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563940/vba-reverse-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach using `Application.Index()` function**

The `Application.Index()` function allows to rearrange columns by passing an *array* of **column numbers** in the wanted order *(here in reversed order `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`)* - c.f. section `[1]` and `[2]`.

Eventually the transposed data are written to a predefined target - c.f. `[3]`

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    'Source declaration following untested OP
    Dim src As Workbook
    Set src= Workbooks.Open("FileName.xls", CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)
    'Define target range's top cell
    Dim tgt As Range: Set tgt = Sheet1.Range("G8")  ' reference target via project's Code(Name)

    With src.Worksheets("SheetSource")
        '[0] get data
        Dim vals: vals = .Range("C10:G10").Value2       ' don't reverse addresses in code line!
        '[1] get new order (array of reversed column numbers)
        Dim cols As Long: cols = UBound(vals, 2): Dim newOrder: ReDim newOrder(1 To cols)
        Dim col As Long:  For col = 1 To cols: newOrder(col) = cols - col + 1: Next col
        '[2] reverse columns in data array
        vals = Application.Index(vals, 1, newOrder)
        
        '[3] write transposed data to target  
        tgt.Resize(UBound(vals), 1) = Application.Transpose(vals)
        
    End With
End Sub
```

**Further reading**

[Some pecularities of the `Application.Index() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)